# How to save an encoded pdf in a zip file using django?

Tags: python, django, zip

I've read some posts about this problem, but most of them didn't help my case, I'm trying to save an encoded pdf in a zip file (I'm using Docraptor API for the pdf generation, which return the encoded pdf).

```
def toZip(request, ...):
    ...
    response = docraptor_api_call() #api call to generate pdf (encoded pdf)

    with open('creation.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response)

    #decode pdf
    with open(f.name, 'rb') as pdf:
        # this will download the pdf to the user
        # doc = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
        # doc['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=filename.pdf" 
        # return doc

        zip_io = io.BytesIO()
        # create zipFile
        zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_io, mode='w')

        # write PDF in ZIP ?
        save_zf = zf.write(pdf.read())

        # save zip to FileField
        zip = ZipStore.objects.create(zip=save_zf)
```

While trying the code on top I get this error :

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 43: character maps to

I'm don't really get what am I doing wrong and how I should fix it, any suggestion ?

Comment: just firing from the hip here, but sounds like you need to change the encoding used where ever the error is coming from.

Comment: @SuperStew The encoding is utf-8, I'm not sure the error is coming from that

Comment: It's possible you need to change it to something else. Or filter out the incompatible characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You've got an error in the way you're calling `zf.write`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html). You should be using:

```
# ZipFile.write would take the the file to write, not bytes to be written.
# f.name is the name of the file in the zip archive. So if I passed 
# in "foo.txt", "1", I'd get a file named `foo.txt` after decompressing, and its
# contents would be 1
zf.writestr(f.name, pdf.read())
```

This method does not appear to return something, so you'll need to change this: `zip = ZipStore.objects.create(zip=save_zf)` probably to:

```
zip = ZipStore.objects.create(zip=zip_io)
```

Comment: The `write` methods don't return anything. objects.create needs to be given something else.